# javascript function problem

Tags: javascript, while-loop

i need one more thing

i have

```
function show_image()
{
  document.write("<img src="+this.link+" ,alt="+this.alt+" ,width=600, height=400>");
}

function image(a,b,c)
{
  this.link=a;
  this.alt=b;
  this.thumb=c;
  this.zobraz=show_image;
}

image1=new image("img/img1.jpg","info image 1","thumb/img1");
image2=new image("img/img2.jpg","info image 2","thumb/img2");
```

and now, i am trying to do something like this:

```
function slideshow()
{
var i=1;
      while(i<3)
{
      document.write(image[i].zobraz());
i++
}
}
```

i don't know why, but this [i] thing is not working.
Where is my mistake?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use an array to be able to subscript using `[]`:

```
// create array to hold images
var images = [];

// load images and store them in the array
images.push(new image(...));
images.push(new image(...));

// .. now subscripting using [] works fine now
var i=0;
while(i<3)
{
   document.write(images[i].zobraz());
   i++
}
```

**NOTE** Array indices are zero-based, i.e. the first entry is at index 0!

Comment: so, i can't continue this way? Basically, my constructor is useless now, right?

Comment: It isn't useless, it is unrelated to the problem - the problem is simply that you didn't create an Array, so accessing using the `[0]` notation doesn't work.

Comment: Small improvement: `while( i < images.length )`.  In case a fourth and fifth image appear...

Comment: this is great. Just one more thing : image.push(new image("img/img2.jpg","info o image 2","thumb/img2")); this is not working for me, but it is not such a big deal

Answer (score 0):

You haven't actually created an array.

Try this:

```
var image = [];
image[0]=new image("img/img1.jpg","info image 1","thumb/img1");
image[1]=new image("img/img2.jpg","info image 2","thumb/img2");
```

and adjust your loop.

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to reference `image1` and `image2` as though they are array elements.

Instead of

```
image1=new image("img/img1.jpg","info image 1","thumb/img1");
image2=new image("img/img2.jpg","info image 2","thumb/img2");
```

Try this:

```
var image = [];
image[1] = new image("img/img1.jpg","info image 1","thumb/img1");
image[2] = new image("img/img2.jpg","info image 2","thumb/img2");
```

Now your function `slideshow()` should work as you've written it.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the array-business stated in the other answers, you're still doing something awkward there:

```
document.write( image[i].zobraz() );
```

If you would expand the `zobraz` call you will see that it doesn't actually return anything.  It would be best to either make `zobraz` *return* the "img" string, or to code simply `image[i].zobraz();`

Comment: i got some weird error(it has displayed image, but alsostated undefined), but i couldn't find the problem. And this is the problem :) thanks

Comment: @sevdah: I saved you asking the next question :)